# E4X: how to add a default namespase to exisitng E4X object

Tags: javascript, xml, namespaces, xml-namespaces, e4x

If the E4X object has been already created, then I am capable to add a new namespaces using, for example:

```
addNamespace( new Namespace( "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ) );
```

However, my attempt to define a default namespace in a similar way fails. There is a workaround by turning this E4X object to a string and replacing the first element but this is a bit artificial.

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is going from here:
`<PRPA_INxxxxxx ITSVersion="XML_1.0">`;

to here (the question is how define "urn:hl7-org:v3"):
`<PRPA_INxxxxxx ITSVersion="XML_1.0" xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">`;

Answer (score 1):

Use the `default xml namespace` statement:

```
default xml namespace = "urn:hl7-org:v3";
```

**References**

- [ECMA-357, Section 12.1: The default xml namespace Statement](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/js/language/ECMA-357.pdf)

Comment: Interesting, I tried the same but with no success, probably I missed something. Here is final code that works: 

default xml namespace = "urn:hl7-org:v3";
var prpa = new XML( msg.toString() );
prpa.addNamespace( new Namespace( "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ) );